# Reuse taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I build a site that require lot of taxonomy terms.
I have products and i want to categorize by manufacturers.
But in every manufacturer i want to have 5(or more) basic sub-category for parts.

```
Manufacturers
-BMW
--Doors
--Lights
--etc
-Audi
--Doors
--Lights
--etc
```

the

```
--Doors
--Lights
--etc
```

will be the same in all Cars(audi /bmw..).

I have create the (Car Manufacturers) and now i have to add for every one the sub-category parts......

I don't want to add every taxonomy with hand for every Manufacturer....

Is any easy way to be able to reuse some taxonomy terms?

What i trying is to have 4-5 views for (parts) and somehow every Car(BMW/audi...) when i go **Manufacturers/Audi/doors** they will show me the view with Part doors for the audi .

Pontus Nilsson has a Brilliant idea to have 2 fields for Manufacturers(audi/bmw) and for part(doors/light...) when i add new product.

The question now is how i can make the paths look like **Manufacturers/Audi/doors** without make every taxonomy term my hand and link them without make 100 views..:/

Comment: Maybe you could split it up to be two vocabularies. Manufacturer and "part type"?

Comment: How i can implimate this ?I mean i can make a view and for every car manufacturer i "insert" the vocabulary "part-type?

Comment: Why not just have two drop downs :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well if you instead of making the taxonomy hierarchical and with a mix of both manufacturers and "part types" you could split to have two entity reference field. One for manufacturer and another one for part. Together they will make two separate drop downs. The original idea you had that once a manufacturer (parent) is created X children (part types) should be created as well is harder to maintain. For example when an other part type is available all manufacturers must be updated. The way with separate manufacturer and spare type they are easier maintained.

Comment: I have update the question.